# Assigning collection object of Tuple<String,String,String> to javascript variable in .NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model with collection of Tuple`<string,string,string>`

```
public class PatientDetails
{    
      public Collection <Tuple<string,string,string>> FieldValidationRules { get; set; }
}
```

View for this is stronglytyped i.e it is the PatientDetails is accessed in cshtml as @Model

Now I want to assign this FieldValidationRules object to a Javascript variable so that I can refer it to do the client Validations as per the rules specified in the collection. To do this I have following line of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     _jsFieldValidationRules = "@Model.FieldValidationRules";
});
```

But I have a problem here that _jsFieldValidationRules doesn't get assigned to the values in "@Model.FieldValidationRules instead it gets assigned to:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection 1[System.Tuple3[System.String,System.String,System.String]]
```

What do I do to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I do to make it work.

Use a Json serializer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    _jsFieldValidationRules = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FieldValidationRules));
});
```